# How to check if "All runtime state associated with app" has been removed for Android app?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My problem is that all alarms related to my app are cleared as soon as I deploy my app to the device.

I think this is because all runtime data is cleared when an app is restarted because this line from the documentaion of broadcast action:  `ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED`
"... All runtime state associated with it (processes, alarms, notifications, etc) should be removed ..."

At first i thoughed `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` would save me as it's triggerd when I deploy a new version, but **when debugging the same version its not triggerd**.

How to check if all my "All runtime state associated with my app"  have been removed?

Basicly I need the [ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED) event, that i cant get in my own app.
Or the [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) event, that does not get fired when the packaged hassnt changed since the last build.

Answer (score 0):

### My temporary solution

Since this problem only occurs when debugging I used gradles support for sourceSets

**build.gradle:**

```
sourceSets {
        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
        }
        release {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/release/res']
        }
    }
```

Each sourceSet has a configuration.xml file in `res/values/` containing a boolean value `release_build`

**res/values/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="release_build">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In the onCreate of my MainActivity if `release_build` is false and the USB is connected, I act as if the data has been cleared:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // Execute startup command if debugging
        if (!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.release_build)) {
            Intent intent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
            executeStartUpAppCommand = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
        }
        ...
    }
```